# How I can to retrieve a JSON object from an AJAX Response?

Tags: json, ajax, response

I have created a JSON object like this:

---File data.php---

```
    var objEquipos={

   "menu" : { 

               "Introducción" : {


                         },

               "Visualización"   : {


                        }
            }


};
```

This objecte JSON is filling up throught with jQuery code as the follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

//var equipos=$('#equiposUL >li > a ');
var equipos1=$('#equipos1  a ');
var equipos2=$('#equipos2  a  ');

    equipos1.each(function(index,element){

  subintro=$(element).text(); 

  objEquipos['menu']['Introducción']['sub_'+index]=subintro;    

   });

equipos2.each(function(index,element){

  subvis=$(element).text(); 

  objEquipos['menu']['Visualización']['sub_'+index]=subvis;

   });
```

And the HTML code is the follow:

```
    <!-- EQUIPOS-->
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='Equipos.html' id="equipos" class="prova" target="central"><span>Equipos</span></a>
   <ul id="equiposUL">
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Introduccion</span></a>
            <ul id="equipos1">
               <li><a href='#'><span>Documentos</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#' id="visualitzación"><span>Visualizacion</span></a>
            <ul id="equipos2">
               <li><a href='#' ><span>Documentación</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Training</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Meeting</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the objEquipos variable in from the second file:

--retrieveDATA.php---

```
   $.get("../interfaz/index.php",function (response) {

  console.log(response);


  });
```

The jQuery code retrieve HTML data, the question is, how I can retrieve only tha "objEquipos" variable without HTML code, because I can not to do this:

```
response.objEquipos;
```

Comment: is that all in one php-file? (exept retrieveData.php of course)

Comment: If I get it right what you want to do, I think it would be better to have that array/json as a php-varaible in a seperate file, that only serves that array/json.

Comment: Tidied title; trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar; layout.

Comment: Furthermore you're about to setup a MVC-Pattern like structure - which is good. But there are MANY freeware frameworks out there that will do that better and quicker for you. Both client-side or server-side.

Comment: how i can generate a json objecte in a separately file , where  the content of this json objecte is from the HTML list , so how i can to do this?, i have to create a php class in order to do this,... PLEASE ,i'm really confuse.

regards